# CodeLens references shortcut doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, codelens

I have CodeLens enabled in my IDE, but for some reason, the [Alt] + 2 shortcut doesn't work anymore.

When using [Alt] + 2 (that should give me the list of references) this is shown instead:

[image]

I have verified that no other function is using [Alt] + 2

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: It seams to work in Visual Studio 2019.
I still had problems in VS 2017, but upgraded a few days ago, and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Visual Studio 2019.